# Is there a way to workaround the Xamarin.Forms Tizen ListView rowheight property limitation for TV?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tizen, television

I am trying to find an alternative to set the row height of a `ListView` in Tizen platform for TV.

As we know there is a limitation related to the `RowHeight` property in Xamarim `ListView` for [Tizen](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-reference/.net-application/current-xamarin.forms-limitations?langredirect=1). 
This property is just ignored so I cannot set the height of the rows in my `ListView`.

Is there a workaround or an alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a TextCell? You cannot set the height of a `TextCell`. Its `Height` property is ignored.

However, if you use a `ViewCell` instead, you can change its height.